# Problema con doble enlace de datos en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy trabajando con Angular y con Angular Material y tengo un problemita, es el siguiente.
Tengo una interfaz con  cierta información. En esta interfaz tengo un botón que abre un modal para editar la información de la interfaz. A este modal le paso un objeto que es el que sera modificado en el modal. Todo esta correcto, si modifico el objeto este se modifica y actualizo en la base de datos que es MongoDB y gracias al doble enlace de datos de Angular no tengo que consultar a la base de datos para actualizar la interfaz con la nueva información. El problema esta cuando cancelo la edición en el modal. Me explico cuando abro el modal y edito la información pero cancelo en vez de guardar vuelvo a la interfaz anterior pero con los datos modificados debido al doble enlace de datos entonces tendría que actualizar la pagina para que la interfaz recuperase la información verdadera y no la modificación que al final nunca se llego a guardar en la base de datos.
Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de evitar este problema para no tener que actualizar la pagina al cancelar la edición en el modal.
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se entiend la pregunta, toma un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que veas un ejempllo de como preguntar, asi se te dara una mejor respuesta a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer pasar una copia nueva del objeto al modal así los cambios en el modal no se verán reflejados en la interfaz cuando canceles. Y cuando la acción sea guardar entonces puedes reemplazar el objeto que tiene los datos en la interfaz con el nuevo objeto que se encuentra en el modal.

Te dejo un ejemplo, no usando modal pero sí la idea de usar copias de objetos:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  objeto: any = {
      nombre :'juan',
      apellido : 'perez'
 };

 objetoCopia = {nombre: '',apellido:''};

 editar(){
   this.objetoCopia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.objeto));
 }
 cancelar(){
   this.objetoCopia = {nombre:'',apellido:''};
 }

 guardarCambios(){
   this.objeto = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.objetoCopia))
   this.objetoCopia = {nombre:'',apellido:''};
 }
}
```

El componente.html:

```
{{objeto.nombre}}<br>
    {{objeto.apellido}}

<br><br>

<input type="button" (click)="editar()" value="editar"/>
<br><br>



<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="objetoCopia.nombre" /><br>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="objetoCopia.apellido" /><br>
<input type="button" (click)="guardarCambios()" value="guardar"/>
<input type="button" (click)="cancelar()" value="cancelar"/>
```

[ejemplo stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkchph)

Comment: Ok voy a intentar eso. Parece buena idea, no se me habia ocurrido. Gracias por la ayuda.